# Not able to install CURL on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, php, curl

When I am trying to install the following error is coming

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gedit : Breaks: gedit-plugins (< 2.91) but 2.30.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can anyone please highlight the issue and give some solution?

Answer (score 1):

For CURL to work, it depends on some other packages.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  gedit : Breaks:
>   gedit-plugins (< 2.91) but 2.30.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed 
>   php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11) but
>   5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 is to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

This explains what all dependcies are not installed.

It is explained in the error itself `apt-get -f install` **may** solve your problem.

If this is not helping, You could try and install the dependencies one after one by downloading and compiling them, or install them directly using terminal.

Comment: I am getting this error on `apt-get -f install`

"No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 gedit-plugins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:

> `sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge gedit`
>
> `sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge gedit`

Followed by a quick

> `apt-get -f install`
>
> `sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge gedit`
>
> `sudo service apache2 restart`

fixed it all.